# Tab bar color become black when hidden swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

as you can see from the picture, the tab bar color is black. I hide the tab bar when segmented control tapped

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        self.viewUIPickerView.viewWithTag(10)?.hidden = false
        self.viewUIPickerView2.viewWithTag(11)?.hidden = true
    }else {
        self.viewUIPickerView2.viewWithTag(11)?.hidden = false
        self.viewUIPickerView.viewWithTag(10)?.hidden = true
    }

    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true

}
```

and i try using`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` still doesnt work.

Comment: Please post how you create the `UISegmentedControl` as well. (Edit your question)

Comment: You have to set a method : [self setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:YES]

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4:**
Programatically

Worked Perfectly for me.

```
func hideTabBar() {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
}

func showTabBar() {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Comment: But when pushing to next controller the animation shows black bar. Is there any way for smooth animation without black bar?

Comment: @jayaraj did fixed that black color while pushing from one viewcontroller to another? Even I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

You are using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the view with the tab controller. But you must set this in the controller that you will push.

Set it into `prepare for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segue.destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

Comment: I didn't know hidesBottomBarWhenPushed exists!
It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

In the Attribute inspector, try to check Extended Edges Under Bottom Bars